# Replace a certain character from a String

Tags: java

In this code, I am trying to replace a letter from a String entered by a user. For example, the program asks for a word, and the user enters "hello", the next variable that the user inputs is the letter that is going to be replaced ("l"), and the final variable is the letter that is going to replace the previous variable ("x").

The result should be "hexxo", but my program is only replacing one of the l's, what is wrong with my program?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Letter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your word:");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter the letter you want to replace:");
        String replace = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter the replacing letter:");
        String add = input.nextLine();
       
        System.out.println(replaceLetter(word, replace, add));
    }
    
    public static String replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String add)
    {
        String newWord = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(letterToReplace))
            {
            String front = word.substring(0, word.indexOf(letterToReplace));
            String back = word.substring(word.indexOf(letterToReplace)+1);
            newWord = front + add + back;
            }
            
        }
        return newWord;
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

First, your program updates `newWord` everytime,
but whenever `newWord` is updated, it is calculated with not-updated `word`.

```java
if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(letterToReplace))
{
    String front = !!!!!word!!!!!.substring(0, word.indexOf(letterToReplace));
    String back = !!!!!word!!!!!.substring(word.indexOf(letterToReplace)+1);
    newWord = front + add + back;
}
```

Second, why `substring()` in the if block does not use `i`?

```java
String front = word.substring(0, !!!!!word.indexOf(letterToReplace)!!!!!);
String back = word.substring(!!!!!word.indexOf(letterToReplace)+1!!!!!);
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your algorithm is not working, is that you're assigning a new String to `newWord` every time you replace a letter. So you will only get an output of the last replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Every time the loop checks the the original string `word`.

First, your program updates `newWord` every-time, but whenever `newWord` is updated, it is calculated with not-updated `word`.

Just remove the variable `newWord` and perform operations on variable `word` only as presented in the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Letter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your word:");
        String word = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter the letter you want to replace:");
        String replace = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter the replacing letter:");
        String add = input.nextLine();
    
        System.out.println(replaceLetter(word, replace, add));
    }
    
    public static String replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String add)
    {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(letterToReplace))
            {
                String front = word.substring(0, word.indexOf(letterToReplace));
                String back = word.substring(word.indexOf(letterToReplace)+1);
                word = front + add + back;
            }
            
        }
        return word;
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `String#replace` or `String#replaceAll`. Just take a look into the java-doc to understand how they work.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using `word.indexOf(letterToReplace)` which will always return the first index of string. So, Instead, you need to use `word.indexOf(letterToReplace,i);` with minor code, changes will help you to solve your problem. Try it yourself.

**Happy Coding !!!**